# After tuning Postgresql, PgBench results are worse

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, performance-testing

I am testing PostgreSQL on an 8gb Ram/4 CPUs/ 80gb SSD cloud server from Digital Ocean. I originally ran PgBench with default settings in the postgresql.conf, and then altered some common settings--shared_buffers, work_mem, maintenance_work_mem, effective_cache_size--to reflect the 8gb of RAM. After running the 2nd set of tests, I noticed that some of my results were actually worse. Any suggestions on why this might be? I am rather new to PgBench and tuning PostgreSQL in general.

**Settings:**

- shared_buffers = 2048mb
- work_mem = 68mb
- maintenance_work_mem = 1024mb
- effective_cache_size = 4096mb

**Tests:**

- pgbench -i -s 100
- pgbench -c 16 -j 2 -T 60 -U postgres postgres
- pgbench -S -c 16 -j 2 -T 60 -U postgres postgres
- pgbench -c 16 -j 4 -T 60 -U postgres postgres
- pgbench -S -c 16 -j 4 -T 60 -U postgres postgres
- pgbench -c 16 -j 8 -T 60 -U postgres postgres
- pgbench -S -c 16 -j 8 -T 60 -U postgres postgres

How effective are these tests? Is this an effective way to employ PgBench? How should I customize tests to properly reflect my data and server instance?

Comment: What are your random_page_cost and cpu_tuple_cost? Try r_p_c at 1.0, then retest with c_t_c at 0.05, then retest c_t_c at 1.0. Does pgbench issue an ANALYZE before running? Are you supposed to do it manually?

Comment: 60 seconds is far too short a period for any write-intensive benchmarking.  You have to benchmark long enough to span over several checkpoints.  Also, you haven't shown us the numbers.  Maybe your before and after were within the margin of error.  The last 3 settings you changed are unlikely to be relevant to the benchmarks you are running.  In addition to shared_buffers, you would want to look at checkpoint_segments.  Finally, changing -j doesn't seem terribly interesting unless you are trying to benchmark the pgbench code itself rather than the database; I'd just always set it equal to -c.

Answer (score 6):

What is mean "worse"? How long time you run pgbench? This test should be executed about 2hour as minimum for realistic values. What version of PostgreSQL do you have?

Attention: You should be very careful about interpretation pgbench result. Probably you should to optimize execution of your application, not pgbench. pgbench is good for hw or sw checking, is bad tool for optimizing of PostgreSQL configuration.

A mentioned configuration variables are basic for configuration and you probably cannot to be wrong there (server must not use a swap actively ever - and these variables ensure it).

A formula that I use:

```
-- Dedicated server 8GB RAM
shared_buffers = 1/3 .. 1/4 dedicated RAM
effecttive_cache_size = 2/3 dedicated RAM

maintenance_work_mem > higher than the most big table (if possible) 
                      else 1/10 RAM 
                      else max_connection * 1/4 * work_mem

work_mem  = precious setting is based on slow query analyse 
            (first setting about 100MB)

--must be true
max_connection * work_mem * 2 + shared_buffers 
          + 1GB (O.S.) + 1GB (filesystem cache) <= RAM size
```

Usually default values of WAL buffer size and checkpoint segments is too low too. And you can increase it.